# Using Ajax to submit a form, and run a SQL Select query based on user input from the form

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, mysql, forms

I'm creating a web form on my WordPress powered website. The form is intended to allow the user to enter a ZIP Code (aka postal code). When the user submits the form, the page should query a MySQL table, SELECT the rows which match the search criteria and dispense those values into a table on the same page.

Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful thus far.

Per the example I followed, three components are necessary to query a SQL table from within a WordPress site:

1. A form, written in PHP, which resides in the .php file for your page template
2. A function which actually executes the SQL query, added to your theme's functions.php file
3. A segment of Javascript code to tie the above two things together

Here is what I have so far.

First, the form code:

```
<form type="post" action="" role="form" id="DirectorySearchForm" class="DirectorySerch">
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Zip Code: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="text" name="inZip" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="DirectorySearch">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" style="font-size: 18pt;">
</form>
<div id="search_results"></div>
```

Second, the function in functions.php:

```
function DirectorySearch() {
    global $wpdb;
    echo "33333";   

    $inZip = $_POST['inZip'];

    $query = 'SELECT OrgName, Phone FROM directory_organizations WHERE Zip_Codes LIKE %s%';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $inZip) );
    echo $results;
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_DirectorySearch', 'DirectorySearch' );    //If called from admin panel
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_DirectorySearch', 'DirectorySearch' );    //If called by non-user
```

Third, the javascript sequence to tie the above two together.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){               
  // get our references
  var $form = $('form.DirectorySerch'),
      $inZip = $('#inZip'),
      $results = $('#search_results');

// on submit, do the search 
  $form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    do_search();
  });

  // AJAX search call
  function do_search() {

    // grab the query value from the search field
    var search_text = $search_field.val();

    // do a POST ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
      data: ({
        action: "DirectorySearch",
        search_text: search_text
      }),
      success: function (response){
        console.log(response);
        $results.html(response);
      }     
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I'm a beginner, so I borrowed heavily from examples of others trying to accomplish the same thing. However, my web form does not generate a query result.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong, or, alternatively, advise me on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you tell me where it is failed like check network if ajax is working or not and then check if it works then it will go to your function.
Have you point out where the issue is or not ?

Comment: Add an id element in your input and in your do_search function get value of id by var search_text = document.getElementById('myzip').value; e.g : myzip is your input id.

If still issue occurs then please tell me.

Comment: More information would be great here - can you confirm that the form handler is executing, and that the POSTed values are present? Does the query execute - what result does it provide?